# JavaScript map two comma separated strings to array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

I've two comma separated strings, which i need to transform it to array of objects

```
{
 "id": "1,2,3",
 "name": "test 1, test 2, test 3"
}
```

How can I get the transformed output as object?

```
{
    "selectedDataConcepts": {
        "dataConcepts": [{
                "id": "1",
                "name": "test 1"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "test 2"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "test 3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Tried multiple ways didn't work, would be glad if someone can provide solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and get ids and names as array and then use it to get the desired result.

```js
const data = { id: "1,2,3", name: "test1, test2, test3" };

const ids = data.id.split(',');
const names = data.name.replaceAll(' ', '').split(',')
const result = {
    selectedDataConcepts: {
        dataConcepts: ids.map((id, index) => ({id, name: names[index]}))
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks :) I don't think .replaceAll(' ', '') is required as it won't work with name having spaces between words for eg: test 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is another way how you can do this task...

```js
const data = { id: "1,2,3", name: "test1, test2, test3" };

const { id, name } = data;
const ids = id.split(',');
const names = name.replaceAll(' ', '').split(',');

const selectedDataConcepts = {
  dataConcepts: ids.map((id, index) => ({id, name: names[index]}))
};

const result = { selectedDataConcepts };

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried a more beautified and readable approach.

```js
const data = { "id": "1,2,3", "name": "test 1, test 2, test 3"}

console.log({
    "selectedDataConcepts": {
        "dataConcepts": data.id.split(",").map((item, index) => {
            return {
                "id": data.id.split(",")[index],
                "name": data.name.split(",")[index].trim()
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First idea that comes to mind, that can definetly be beautified more:

```js
function mapToDataConcepts(object) {
  const idArr= object.id.split(',');
  const nameArr = object.name.replaceAll(' ','').split(',');
  const output = {selectedDataConcepts:[]};

  idArr.forEach((id, index) => {
    output.selectedDataConcepts.push({id:idArr[index], name: nameArr[index]});
  });
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this:

```js
const data = { id: "a,b,c", name: "test1, test2, test3" };

const json = {
    "selectedDataConcepts" : {
        "dataConcepts": data.name.split(',').map((name,i) => ({id:data.id.split(',')[i], name}))
    }
}
console.log(json);
```